# Visual Studio 2017 Collapsing also removes unused using

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, using-directives

I am dealing with the unfortunate situation of using a temporary PC for my work right now, and the pre-installed `Visual Studio 2017` is determined to make my life hard.

When I collapse content in the `C#` editor (Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>), not only does it collapse content, but it also goes ahead and removes all the unused `using` statements, which is NOT what I want it to do. I can't figure out why.

Is there some hidden setting that might let me turn this feature (if it is a feature at all) ON/OFF?

Comment: There must be a conflicting keyboard shortcut in that particular PC. I tried in VS2017 Community Edition but the unused using statements were NOT removed. Also, I have Resharper installed as well

Comment: Damn this is going to be a nightmare. :(

Comment: What if you press Ctrl-Z after collapsing the content? That should be enough to undo the remove using statements ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I painstakingly went through the entire `Option` window and found it!

Go to:

> **Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting**

And the following option is the culprit:

[image]

God that's buried under a mountain of stuff.

### EDIT:

In case the image link ever gets broken, uncheck the `Remove unnecessary usings` under `Perform additional code cleanup during formatting` section.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was driving me nuts!

Comment: Gone in VS2019 :(

Answer (score 3):

Go to **`Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Keyboard`**.

You can check what action(s) is/are assigned to the <kbd>Ctrl + M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> keyboard shortcut by pressing that shortcut in the "`Press Shortcut keys`" textbox as follows:

[image: Check keyboard shortcut]

The other action you're interested at is called "`Remove and sort`", you can find it using the "`Show commands containing`" textbox, and then check which shortcut is assign to it (if any):

[image: Search shortcut results]

### EDIT

In case you're using Resharper, check also for the following shortcuts:

[image: Resharper shortcuts]

Comment: I don't see a conflict in my options. `Collapse` has the `Ctrl + M + O` assigned to it, and `Remove and Sort` doesn't have a shortcut assigned.

Comment: @Sach edited my answer. Are you using Resharper BTW?

Comment: No, I'm not using Resharper. I looked through shortcuts, it doesn't look like a conflict with shortcuts.

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks for your effort!